# How to hide the sidebar in a mediawiki site when you are not logged in

Tags: javascript, css, mediawiki

On my mediawiki site, you need to log in to view and edit pages. But the sidebar is displayed even when you are not logged in. Since there is some confidential information, I would like to show the sidebar only when you are logged in.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Left grey box should be hidden

[image: 1]

Right now, I have these restrictions in LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgWhitelistRead = array( "Spezial:Userlogin", "MediaWiki:Monobook.css", "api.php"); 
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false; $wgGroupPermissions['user']['protect'] = true; 
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = true; $wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75426892/2817442) and [Robert's comment](https://sangkrit.net/how-to-hide-mediawiki-sidebar-from-visitors/#comment-361956) on the [site](https://sangkrit.net/how-to-hide-mediawiki-sidebar-from-visitors/) referenced:

This can be done by creating a new PHP file in extensions folder then including the code in LocalSettings.php file.

Login to your MediaWiki website’s file manager or FTP, navigate to /extensions directory located in your site’s root and create a new folder /HideSidebar.

Open the folder, create a new PHP file with name HideSidebar.php and paste the following (**Updated**) code:

```
<?php

if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    echo "Not a valid entry point";
    exit( 1 );
}

$wgExtensionCredits['other'][] = array(
    'path' => __FILE__,
    'name' => 'HideSidebar',
    'version' => '1.0.1',
    'author' => 'Jlerner',
    'url' => 'https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HideSidebar',
    'description' => 'Allows to hide the sidebar from anonymous users',
);

$wgHooks['SkinBuildSidebar'][] = 'efHideSidebar';
 
function efHideSidebar($skin, &$bar) {
        $user = RequestContext::getMain()->getUser();
        // Hide sidebar for anonymous users
        if ($user->getId() == 0) {
                $url = Title::makeTitle(NS_SPECIAL, 'UserLogin')->getLocalUrl();
                $bar = array(
                        'navigation' => array(
                                array('text'   => 'Login',
                                      'href'   => $url,
                                      'id'     => 'n-login',
                                      'active' => '')
                        )
                );
        }
        return true;
}
```

Now open LocalSettings.php file and add this line of code:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/HideSidebar/HideSidebar.php";
```

Save changes and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to remove the sidenavbar when you are not logged in there is two way.

1. Use a token for it and.
2. Use a state give it's initial value false, when the login api success then true the state with this condition also you need your user id to check if it's there then show the sidenavbar.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research for you and I found this, it should be what you are looking for.

CREDIT: https://sangkrit.net/how-to-hide-mediawiki-sidebar-from-visitors/

You can suppress the display of the sidebar from anonymous and un-logged-in users on your MediaWiki website. This can be done by creating a new PHP file in extensions folder then including the code in LocalSettings.php file.

Login to your MediaWiki website’s file manager or FTP, navigate to /extensions directory located in your site’s root and create a new folder /HideSidebar.

Open the folder, create a new PHP file with name HideSidebar.php and paste the following code:

```
<?php

if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    echo "Not a valid entry point";
    exit( 1 );
}

$wgExtensionCredits['other'][] = array(
    'path' => __FILE__,
    'name' => 'HideSidebar',
    'version' => '1.0.1',
    'author' => 'Jlerner',
    'url' => 'https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HideSidebar',
    'description' => 'Allows to hide the sidebar from anonymous users',
);

$wgHooks['SkinBuildSidebar'][] = 'efHideSidebar';
 
function efHideSidebar($skin, &$bar) {
        global $wgUser;
        // Hide sidebar for anonymous users
        if (!$wgUser->isLoggedIn()) {
                $url = Title::makeTitle(NS_SPECIAL, 'UserLogin')->getLocalUrl();
                $bar = array(
                        'navigation' => array(
                                array('text'   => 'Login',
                                      'href'   => $url,
                                      'id'     => 'n-login',
                                      'active' => '')
                        )
                );
        }
        return true;
}
```

Now open LocalSettings.php file and add this line of code:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/HideSidebar/HideSidebar.php";
```

Save changes and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just need to look for the `body`'s `class` when logged in, and if it's `.logged-in`, do something like this:

```
body:not(.logged-in) .sidebar{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the code is then still transferred. I would prefer that mediawiki does not even deliver html code for the side bar when not logged in.

Comment: I've started a bounty, I hope that someone will help you in this.